# How can I monitor a file asynchronously in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I want to monitor a plain text file on windows machine for changes to it. Whenever external application updates the file, my add-on is supposed to read it and act accordingly.

Going through quite bit of documentation I could not find a direct facility to do this in Firefox. So I came up the following approaches.

Please suggest.

Approach 1 -
In a while loop {
  a) List all the files in the directory being monitored / Use nsIFile.exists()
  b) If files does exist go to next step else go to sleep
  c) use "nsIFile" interface and obtain the attribute "lastModifiedTime" of the file & compare it with value stored initially
  d) Sleep for 1 second.
}
I intend to use NetUtil.asyncFetch() for reading this file.
Roadblocks being a) bypassing security b) performance hit when called in main thread.
Though this is not asynchronous in real sense .. I can call this as .js in "ChromeWorker" Thread

Tried above approach ..
but I could not sleep .. seems there is no way to sleep .. setTimeOut() did not help me

Approach 2 -
Little far fetched, not sure if this will work :)
Open the 'nsIFile' as 'nsIInputStreamPump' if file exists

Comment: In nightly, OS.File.watch landed so you can use that now. Windows only right now though. Mac and linux are in the works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in API to get notified about file changes. However, you could use [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/js-ctypes/) to call OS functions directly. So on Windows you would create a `ChromeWorker` and call [`FindFirstChangeNotification` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) there. You would then use a loop with the following calls:

- [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - wait for something to change in the directory you are watching.
- Send change notification to the main thread if necessary.
- [`FindNextChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And you should call [`FindCloseChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) once you are done watching.

Comment: From documentation I could make out that we can use "js-ctypes" inside a chrome worker. However one has to use "FindNextChangeNotification" & "ReadDirectoryChanges" which are C++, so I have to write shim for them first. Again since Gecko 8.0, calling XPCOM from inside ChromeWorkers is not permitted, so I will have to pass all the data read from the file to the main JS thread using listener/event object. I think this is a long way.

Comment: Nice Suggestion - Implemented it :)

Comment: @dpb i was wondering if you accomplished this in js-ctypes, it would be awesome to see!

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I'm fairly certain this can't be done without some sort of polling approach (ie: check the file over some interval or just before you are about to use it).