# How to use ReadDirectoryChangesW in XULRunner (js-ctypes)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xulrunner, jsctypes

I'm trying to implement the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495227/how-can-i-monitor-a-file-asynchronously-in-firefox) about monitoring a Windows filesystem asynchronously. I'm using js ctypes within a ChomeWorker as part of a XULRunner application but I assume this would be the same if I implemented as a Firefox add-on.

As part of the task, I have tried to declare the function ReadDirectoryChangesW as follows (based on my limited knowledge of js ctypes and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

```
const BOOL = ctypes.bool;
const DWORD = ctypes.uint32_t;
const LPDWORD = ctypes.uint32_t.ptr;
const HANDLE = ctypes.int32_t;
const LPVOID = ctypes.voidptr_t;

var library = self.library = ctypes.open("Kernel32.dll");

ReadDirectoryChangesW = library.declare(
  "ReadDirectoryChangesW"
, ctypes.winapi_abi
, BOOL    // return type
, HANDLE  // hDirectory
, LPVOID  // lpBuffer
, DWORD   // nBufferLength
, BOOL    // bWatchSubtree
, DWORD   // dwNotifyFilter
, LPDWORD // lpBytesReturned
);
```

In addition (not featured here), I have declared function mappings for `FindFirstChangeNotification()` and `WaitForSingleObject()` which seem to work fine.

The problem I have is that when a filesystem event occurs, I have no idea what I'm supposed to pass in to the lpBuffer argument, or how to interpret the result.

All of the C++ examples seem to use a `DWORD` array and then cast out the results. My attempt at that is as follows:

```
const DWORD_ARRAY = new ctypes.ArrayType(DWORD);  
var lBuffer = new DWORD_ARRAY(4000);
var lBufferSize = DWORD.size * 4000;
var lBytesOut = new LPDWORD();

ReadDirectoryChangesW(lHandle, lBuffer.address(), lBufferSize, true, WATCH_ALL, lBytesOut)
```

This seems to just crash XULRunner every time.

Can anyone suggest what I should pass in for the lpBuffer argument and/or how to get results back from `ReadDirectoryChangesW()`? All I can find online is C++ examples and they're not a lot of help. Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass NULL for the two extra optional arguments?

Comment: I tried that, but similarly, I have no idea what I'm supposed to suggest the data types are. In any case, even when providing null values for these, it still crashes XULRunner.

Comment: Cool project you got going. Firefox plans to implement something like tihs: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/305/how-to-get-notification-of-file-modified/

Comment: Not any time soon, but if I get this to work, I'll package it up nicely for other Add-on / app authors to use. Note that I'm only really doing the Windows part right now.

Comment: How's this going man?

Comment: @WladamirPalant told in this topic how to do async with ctypes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23884248/1828637

Comment: @Noitidart still couldn't figure out how to get the results out. I'm thinking I'll probably write a DLL that deals with all of that stuff and has a simpler API that is easier to use from js-ctypes.

Comment: Hey man did you get this working? Im trying to get notification when a ini file change.s

Comment: In nightly, OS.File.watch landed so you can use that now. Windows only right now though. Mac and linux are in the works.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't look like OS.File.watch is actually a directly usable API (yet), and it's certainly not documented - I assume this will be the case until it is available on all platforms. However, it IS possible to hook into the XPCOM service nsINativeFileWatcherService under Windows right now as per the tests in https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=992894

Comment: Hey @Ben if you got this working in ctypes that would be real fun to see, were you able to make any more progress on this?

Comment: Hey man i started work on this, can you share your work please i think it might help me out. https://github.com/Noitidart/jscFileWatcher/blob/master/modules/workers/myWorker.js#L141

Comment: Editted into solution below working synchronus version. Im working on async version, having some difficulty with it, ReadDirectoryChangesW keeps giving me winLastError of 6 which is INVALID_HANDLE

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaner solution: read the comments, lots of learning there. For type definitions, [see here](https://github.com/Noitidart/jscFileWatcher/blob/36d53bc6b19f36e4612658b90260f4d4cbd2c49d/modules/ostypes_win.jsm).

```
var path = OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir; // path to monitor

var hDirectory = ostypes.API('CreateFile')(path, ostypes.CONST.FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | ostypes.CONST.GENERIC_READ, ostypes.CONST.FILE_SHARE_READ | ostypes.CONST.FILE_SHARE_WRITE, null, ostypes.CONST.OPEN_EXISTING, ostypes.CONST.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | ostypes.CONST.FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, null);
console.info('hDirectory:', hDirectory.toString(), uneval(hDirectory));
if (ctypes.winLastError != 0) { //cutils.jscEqual(hDirectory, ostypes.CONST.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)) { // commented this out cuz hDirectory is returned as `ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.UInt64("0xb18"))` and i dont know what it will be when it returns -1 but the returend when put through jscEqual gives `"breaking as no targetType.size on obj level:" "ctypes.voidptr_t(ctypes.UInt64("0xb18"))"`
    console.error('Failed hDirectory, winLastError:', ctypes.winLastError);
    throw new Error({
        name: 'os-api-error',
        message: 'Failed to CreateFile',
    });
}

var dummyForSize = ostypes.TYPE.FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION.array(1)(); // accept max of 1 notifications at once (in application you should set this to like 50 or something higher as its very possible for more then 1 notification to be reported in one read/call to ReadDirectoryChangesW)
console.log('dummyForSize.constructor.size:', dummyForSize.constructor.size);
console.log('ostypes.TYPE.DWORD.size:', ostypes.TYPE.DWORD.size);
var dummyForSize_DIVIDED_BY_DwordSize = dummyForSize.constructor.size / ostypes.TYPE.DWORD.size;

console.log('dummyForSize.constructor.size / ostypes.TYPE.DWORD.size:', dummyForSize_DIVIDED_BY_DwordSize, Math.ceil(dummyForSize_DIVIDED_BY_DwordSize)); // should be whole int but lets round up with Math.ceil just in case

var temp_buffer = ostypes.TYPE.DWORD.array(Math.ceil(dummyForSize_DIVIDED_BY_DwordSize))();
var temp_buffer_size = temp_buffer.constructor.size; // obeys length of .array
console.info('temp_buffer.constructor.size:', temp_buffer.constructor.size); // will be Math.ceil(dummyForSize_DIVIDED_BY_DwordSize)

var bytes_returned = ostypes.TYPE.DWORD();
var changes_to_watch = ostypes.CONST.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | ostypes.CONST.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | ostypes.CONST.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME; //ostypes.TYPE.DWORD(ostypes.CONST.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | ostypes.CONST.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | ostypes.CONST.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME);

console.error('start hang');
var rez_RDC = ostypes.API('ReadDirectoryChanges')(hDirectory, temp_buffer.address(), temp_buffer_size, true, changes_to_watch, bytes_returned.address(), null, null);

var cntNotfications = 0;
var cOffset = 0;
while (cOffset < bytes_returned) {
    cntNotfications++;
    var cNotif = ctypes.cast(temp_buffer.addressOfElement(cOffset), ostypes.TYPE.FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION.ptr).contents; // cannot use `temp_buffer[cOffset]` here as this is equivlaent of `temp_buffer.addressOfElement(cOffset).contents` and cast needs a ptr
    console.info('cNotif:', cNotif.toString());
    cOffset += cNotif.NextEntryOffset; // same as doing cNotif.getAddressOfField('NextEntryoffset').contents // also note that .contents getter makes it get a primaive value so DWORD defined as ctypes.unsigned_long will not be returned as expected ctypes.UInt64 it will be primative (due to the .contents getter), so no need to do the typical stuff with a `var blah = ctypes.unsigned_long(10); var number = blah.value.toString();`
}
console.info('total notifications:', cntNotifications);
```

I'm working on getting the async version working but having a tricky time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I learned as I'm working on doing the same now, still in progress

- You have to create a buffer of DWORD so `var buf = ctypes.ArrayType(DWORD, BUFSIZE)` as it needs to be aligned on DWORD boundary, whatever this means
- I don't know what `BUFSIZE` should be exactly but i have seen 2048 and 4096, I don't know why. I have also seen BUFSIZE of 1024*64, no idea why
- Then after succesfully running `ReadDirectoryChangesW` cast this buffer to `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` and then read its contents
- Pass `null` to the final 2 arguments only if you don't want async, we want async so we are going to use the `LPOVERLAPPED` struct and pass it there.

### Edit

Here's solution for sync: This successfully reads one event. If have more you have to move over in temp_buff by next_entry_offset and cast, [see here](https://github.com/Noitidart/jscFileWatcher/tree/36d53bc6b19f36e4612658b90260f4d4cbd2c49d). Install that addon and make a new folder on your desktop or something, and it will log in browser console.

I'm working on async version, having some trouble with that.